A question based on counting total numbers possible using sticks and rings
Recently, I stumbled across an interesting  fun game. In it, one had to form different numbers using two sticks (| |) and two rings (O O), in 30 seconds. You could make numbers like 1010, 11, 1, 0 etc. . The catch point is that you could use | and O together to form a 6 or a 9!! Now I thought about it a little bit and had a question. It is as follows:

How many unique numbers (any number of digits) can be formed using  two sticks and two rings? (Hint: a stick and a ring can together be presented as a 9 or a 6, two rings as an 8, and two sticks as a 7.) For example, 7 , 87, 16 etc. are possible.

One of the answers that I was able to think of was that to use a grouping method as followed:

1100 --> 700(grouping the 1s){700--> 78(grouping last two elements)}, 160(grouping the middle two elements), and 118(grouping the last two elements). So 5 for 1100

Similarly group the other 5 possible permutations of two 1s and two 2s, we get 30. Then take 3 elements, either two sticks and a ring or the other case. Make cases of them to get 9 more solutions, and finally take 2 elements, getting 11, 00, 01, 10 and getting 2 other unique solutions( 0 and 8). This is the most basic solution I could think of, but what will be the most efficient solution to this problem?(I just know  high school math:) )
